# Target_size image_gen.flow_from_dataframe InceptionResNetV2 (Keras) for smaller images

Tags: python, keras

I have a dataset (Tiny ImageNet) where the images are `64 x 64` but I want to use the pre-trained model: InceptionResNetV2 since the accuracy on all other models is low.

Can I double the dimensions in target_size to `128, 128` in the `image_gen.flow_from_dataframe` function and use the output in the InceptionResNetV2?

Will doubling the target size influence the training? I mean will it stretch the images or add blank space around them.

Is this way appropriate or is there a better way to train tiny images using InceptionResNetV2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either define input image size in `ImageDataGenerator` (`target_size=(224,224)`) or in `tf.keras.layers.Input( shape=input_shape )` part.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did? Is it OK? I was apprehensive that it might add some space around my images which may give wrong results? 
Will doubling the size do that or just stretch the images?? @Erdal GENC

Comment: Have you tried it with reasonable test accuracy on the Tiny ImageNet dataset?

Comment: do you mean comparing two resizing methods?

Comment: No, just want to know if resizing influences the predictions. I mean if the test predictions are reasonably accurate for the smaller images, then we are doing fine, isn't it? @Erdal

Comment: I'm not sure. It depends on many things actually. image size is only one of the variables in a model.